# Coffeescript: Is it possible to conditionally declare property without always creating a key?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Let's say I want to create an object where some members aren't always present

```
t = {a: 1, b: b if b}
console.log t       # { a: 1, b: undefined }
```

I'm trying to achieve this result when b is missing

```
t = {a: 1}
if b then t.b = b
console.log t       # { a: 1 }
```

Is there a way I can declare b conditionally without creating the key, and without having a separate line of code?

Comment: What do you mean? What condition are you evaluating? Need a clearer example...'if false' is obviously always going to be false...and any property you haven't specified as otherwise will return `undefined` when queried with the access operators `.`/`[]`

Comment: *"without having a separate line of code"* - Why? Is that line of code hurting you?

Comment: @Tomalak Just trying to see if there's coffeescript tricks I don't know

Comment: I suggest reading the CoffeeScript documentation then. Have you?

Comment: No you can't the closer as you get by one line and conditional key is that
`t = {a: 1}; t.b = b if b`

Comment: Just write that line of code.

Comment: Ain't possible. I'd go with `if b then t = {a: 1, b: b} else t = {a: 1}`

Answer (score 0):

When you need to do it repeatedly on a large object, you could do

```coffee
t = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(
  a: 1
  b: b
  c: 2
).filter(e=>e[1]))
```

This would filter out the `b` property if `b` is falsey.